# JUnit 5 how to assert this !=null

Tags: junit5

I want to test this piece of block mainly in `x != null`, is there a better way to assert this method in JUnit.

```java
private void myorder()
{
    if (x != null)
    {
        //some code
        myorder(x.getDown());
        System.out.print(r.getData() + " ");
        myorder(x.getUp());
    }
}
```

Here's what I've done so far:

```java
@Test
assertFalse(x != null);
```

Comment: I'm not sure there's enough information to understand your problem. If you are trying to test the code within the `if (x != null) { ... }` code block then just set x to a non-null value in your test method. Likewise if you want to test the `myOrder()` method without the `if (x != null) { ... }` code block, then set `x = null` in the test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use Assertions class.

```java
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNotNull;

assertNotNull(x);
```